# PHP/MySQL (eFiction) Preventing Multiple Ratings from single user

Tags: php, mysql, templatepower

On my site (which uses the CMS [eFiction](https://github.com/eFiction/v3_stable)) users can leave reviews with a rating on chapters of 1-10, if they don't rate the chapter it's logged on the table as a -1. I want to prevent users from leaving multiple ratings. My PHP knowledge is very limited, I believe the code should go before line 144 in review.php ([on github here](https://github.com/eFiction/v3_stable/blob/master/reviews.php))

```
dbquery("INSERT INTO ".TABLEPREFIX."fanfiction_reviews (item, type, reviewer, review, rating, date, uid, chapid) VALUES ('$item', 'ST', '$reviewer', '$review', '$rating', now(), '".(USERUID && isNumber(USERUID) ? USERUID : 0)."', '$chapid')");
```

I'm trying to write a query for the fanfiction_reviews table and if finds an entry that matched the uid (user) and chapid and has a rating, throw them an error message that they already rated the chapter. ETA: To answer a question below, I want the 2nd rating to be ignored or not logged, rather than replacing a previous rating.

As I mentioned, my PHP is limited, I just try to mimic what I find elsewhere in eFiction. Edit: in the following initially had changed `useruid = '$uid'` which was giving me a fatal mysql error. I changed it to `uid = '$uid'` and the stopped the error

```
$ratecount = dbquery("select count(rating) as count FROM ".TABLEPREFIX."fanfiction_reviews WHERE item = '$item' AND chapid = '$chapid' AND uid = '$uid' AND rating != '-1'");
if($ratecount != 0) $output .= write_error(_MULTIPLERATINGS);
```

With the above pasted in the file, it does give me the "multiple rating error" message BUT it's still logging the rating. How do I get it to not log the rating (or change it to the non-rating of -1)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: For the sake of others when answering, can you specify what you want to happen if a user attempts to rate more than once. Should the second rating superseded the first or be ignored?

Comment: Why log `-1`, just dont write and on the app side if no record display what you display for `-1`. After that you can set up a unique key on the columns as you need it (something like unique (userid, chapter, bookid)).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't be discouraged by the comments. Yours is a good first question and will soon be a very good one.

Comment: @chris85 It's how the eFiction software is set up, if the user doesn't rate a chapter, the rating gets logged as (-1), I'm not sure how I would begin to change that. Each review/rating does get logged with a unique ID under a reveiwid column

Answer (score 0):

Try `if($ratecount.count != 0) $output .= write_error(_MULTIPLERATINGS);`. It's also possible you may need to format it as `if($ratecount["count"] != 0) $output .= write_error(_MULTIPLERATINGS);`.

As yet another contingency, you might need to loop through the result set, or put a [0] in there to indicate that you want to access the "count" field of the first row in the result set. Your mileage may vary depending on exactly what dbquery() does. Keep in mind that there are many different ways of connecting to, and interacting with a database in php, and different implementations may return results in different ways, and may adhere to slightly different conventions. AFAIK, dbquery() is not a standard function in php.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edit the code above so it's at least no longer giving me a fatal mysql error but it's still logging the rating. I tried the 2 methods you posted, but they both give me errors, `if($ratecount.count != 0)` gives me "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string" while `if($ratecount["count"] != 0)` gives me
"Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in reviews.php Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in reviews.php on line X". eFiction is very ancient so it's probably not even written in the right form of PHP.